# Wrapping apk with MDX ToolKit - Failed to merge resources from ManagedApp

Tags: android, citrix, xenapp

I have been trying to generate build with Citrix - MDX ToolKit which takes in `.apk` file and generates `.mdx` file which can be exported with Mobile Device Management used by many organization to secure their application data.

Tried :

- Android Studio generates build without any complain even by restricting the lint checks. Though it may throws warning but certainly not regarding `strings` and their duplicates.

Getting following error while converting `.apk` tool with `MDX ToolKit`

```
E: Failed to merge resources from ManagedApp
```

Following is the error log :

```
 Unpacking app: App-production-release...
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 I: Using Apktool 2.3.1 on App-production-release.apk
 I: Loading resource table...
 I: Decoding AndroidManifest.xml with resources...
 I: Loading resource table from file: 
 /Users/abc/Library/apktool/mdx/framework/2.3.1/1.apk
 I: Regular manifest package...
 I: Decoding file-resources...
 I: Decoding values x/x XMLs...
 I: Copying raw classes.dex file...
 I: Copying assets and libs...
 I: Copying unknown files...
 I: Copying original files...



 Analyzing app...
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 I: Loading classes.dex
 I: Moved application code to classes2.dex
 I: Non-Intune application.
 I: Added ManagedApp as classes.dex
 I: Added library: lib/x86/liblog4cpp.so
 I: Added library: lib/x86/libctxlog.so
 I: Added library: lib/x86/libmdxlib.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi-v7a/libDataProtection.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi-v7a/libfullsslsdk.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi-v7a/libCtxTFE.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi-v7a/liblog4cpp.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi-v7a/libctxlog.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi-v7a/libmdxlib.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi-v7a/libctxjni.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi-v7a/libns-gateway.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi/libDataProtection.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi/libfullsslsdk.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi/libCtxTFE.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi/liblog4cpp.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi/libctxlog.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi/libmdxlib.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi/libctxjni.so
 I: Added library: lib/armeabi/libns-gateway.so
 I: Adding asset file assets/pac/pac.js
 I: Added Resources from assets/mdx/frameworks/0/org.apache.http.legacy.jar
 I: No AndroidManifest to merge from 
 assets/mdx/frameworks/0/org.apache.http.legacy.jar
 I: Added Manifest elements from 
 assets/mdx/frameworks/0/org.apache.http.legacy.jar
 I: Added optional library assets/mdx/frameworks/0/org.apache.http.legacy.jar
 I: Skipped adding optional library assets/mdx/frameworks/1/adal/gson- 
 2.2.4.jar
 I: Skipped adding optional library assets/mdx/frameworks/1/adal/adal- 
 1.11.0.jar
 I: Added Resources from assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support-fragment- 
 25.3.1.jar
 I: Added Manifest elements from assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support- 
 fragment-25.3.1.jar
 I: Added optional library assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support-fragment- 
 25.3.1.jar
 I: Added Resources from assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support-core-utils- 
 25.3.1.jar
 I: Added Manifest elements from assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support-core- 
 utils-25.3.1.jar
 I: Added optional library assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support-core-utils- 
 25.3.1.jar
 I: Added Resources from assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support-core-ui- 
 25.3.1.jar
 I: Added Manifest elements from assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support-core- 
 ui-25.3.1.jar
 I: Added optional library assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support-core-ui- 
 25.3.1.jar
 I: Added Resources from assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support-media-compat- 
 25.3.1.jar
 I: Added Manifest elements from assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support- 
 media-compat-25.3.1.jar
 I: Added optional library assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/support-media- 
 compat-25.3.1.jar
 W: Resource collision after merging 
 assets/mdx/frameworks/1/support/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.jar
 /Users/abc/Apps/dd9ded47-48fa-4e5e-8cff-d07571d3b70e/res/values- 
 af/values-af_ctx6.xml:3: error: Resource entry 
 abc_action_bar_home_description is already defined.
 /Users/abc/Apps/dd9ded47-48fa-4e5e-8cff-d07571d3b70e/res/values- 
 af/strings.xml:3: Originally defined here.

 /Users/abc/Apps/dd9ded47-48fa-4e5e-8cff-d07571d3b70e/res/values-af/values- 
 af_ctx6.xml:4: error: Resource entry abc_action_bar_home_description_format 
 is already defined.
 /Users/abc/Apps/dd9ded47-48fa-4e5e-8cff-d07571d3b70e/res/values- 
 af/strings.xml:4: Originally defined here.
```

Comment: anybody got answer for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Updating MDXToolkit to version 10.8.60 solved the problem (no more failures).

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.)